# Flattening JSON but keep original properties

Tags: json

I am trying to flatten properties (i.e. objects, array) of a JSON object, but keep the original properties the same, and turn non-scalar properties into strings.

(I'm doing this because when I use the `flat` npm package, arrays/objects are flattened, but object keys are surrounded by `''` , like in `'task_status.0.data'` and do not get stored into AzureTables). If there is a way to fix that and de-string that, it would be an ok solution as well...)

Here's an example you could run on jsfiddle.net

```
var obj1 = {
    "studentId": "abc",
    "task_status": [
            {
                "status":"Current",
                "date":516760078
            },
            {
                "status":"Late",
                "date":1516414446
            }
        ],
    "student_plan": "n"
 }

FlattenJson = function(obj){
    keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var newObj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        var theType = typeof(obj[keys[i]]);
    console.log(theType);
        if(theType === 'array' || theType === 'object'){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj[keys[i]]));
            newObj[keys[i]] = "\"" + JSON.stringify(obj[keys[i]]) + "\"";
        }
        newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return newObj;
}

var newObj1 = FlattenJson(obj1);
console.log(newObj1, obj1);
```

However, the `newobj1` contains the same original array, instead of a string. How would I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED:** Thanks to [this](https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197) you have a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/LL3r7o66/1/).

```
var obj1 = {
    "studentId": "abc",
    "task_status": [
            {
                "status":"Current",
                "date":516760078
            },
            {
                "status":"Late",
                "date":1516414446
            }
        ],
    "student_plan": "n"
 }

function customToString (obj) {
    var str = '{';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            str += prop + ':"' + obj[prop] + '",';
        }
    }
    return str.replace(/.$/,'') + '}';
}

var flattenObject = function(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
};

var newObj1 = flattenObject(obj1);
console.log(newObj1, obj1);
document.write(customToString(newObj1));
```

Comment: this causes the same issue i have with the 'flat' npm package - it causes string-ified versions of the flattened property's key as described above.

Comment: thanks but the customToString causes some weird behavior - still trying to figure it out, but essentially adds 590 empty elements to my array and stringifies them together

Comment: You can add a condition to check if element is empty or not.
Like: `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && isEmpty(obj[prop])) {`